# Producing message using multiple topics in kafka - node.js?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using [Prozess](https://github.com/cainus/Prozess) kafka library in my application for producing the logs. It is working great using the single topic.

#### code

```
    var Producer = require('prozess').Producer;
    var eventKafkaProducer = new Producer('triggerEventTopic', {
        host : 'localhost'
    });
    eventKafkaProducer.connect();
    eventKafkaProducer.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("Error occurred in kafka producer", err);
     });
    eventKafkaProducer.on('brokerReconnectError', function(err) {
        console.log("could not reconnect kafka", err);
    });
```

#### Requirement

How to setup for multiple topics

Whether `Prozess` library will support for multiple topic?

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't use the library, but based on the api it looks like you just need to create another producer. So:

```
var Producer = require('prozess').Producer;

// topic one:
var ops_one = {
  // some options
}

var one = new Producer('one', opts_one)
producer.connect()
// etc.

// topic two:
var opts_two = {
  // some options
}}

var two = new Producer('two', opts_two)
two.connect()
```

Now when you have stuff that should go out in topic one, you just call `one.send("Hey everybody, I'm producer one")`, and you'd do likewise for `two`.